# Open mp3 files with my app

Tags: c#, winforms, mp3

I set my app as default mp3 file reader and I get the target with `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` and It's work well.
But When I select for eg. Three mp3 files and I click enter, It open three windows and each one play a song

```
 foreach (string s in Environment.GetCommandLineArgs())
        {
            if (s.Contains(".mp3"))
            {
                string[] separators = { @"\" };
                string[] filename = s.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                listBox1.Items.Add(filename[filename.Length - 1]);

                array_music.Add(s);
            }
        }

        if (array_music.Count > 0)
        {
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = (string)array_music[0];

        }
```

Comment: can you please update question with your code?

Comment: It would be a lot easier to help you if you posted the code that launches the 3 files as well as any relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Playlist and add each file like below,

```
WMPLib.IWMPPlaylist playlist = wmp.playlistCollection.newPlaylist("myplaylist");
if (args.Length > 0)
{
    foreach (string file in args)
    {
        WMPLib.IWMPMedia media = wmp.newMedia(file);
        playlist.appendItem(media);
    }
    wmp.currentPlaylist = playlist;
    wmp.Ctlcontrols.play();
}
```